# Filtering a PostgreSQL function that returns a table in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to solve the following two problems:

1. Constructing an ORM model to use in SQLAlchemy with a table that is generated from a user defined function in PostgreSQL
2. Filtering said table (either in ORM model or not)

I have defined a function that returns a table called `transformed`. It takes a user_id as an input and returns 3 columns. Looks something like this below (this is extremely simplified, the query is obviously a little more complicated).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transformed (user_id integer)
    RETURNS TABLE (
        id integer,
        user varchar,
        description varchar,
    )
    AS $body$
SELECT
    id,
    user,
    description
FROM table
WHERE id = $1

$body$
LANGUAGE sql;
```

```py
def build_query(user_id):
    base_query: Query = select(
        Column("id", Integer),
        Column("user", String),
        Column("description", String),
    ).select_from(func.transformed)_data(user_id))
    return base_query
```

I have no problem getting the three columns. The challenge is to filter and sort them.

```py
query = build_query(user_id).filter_by(description = "Foo")
```

This returns the following error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Entity namespace for "transformed(:transformed_1) has no property "description".`

I would love to know how to either a) properly filter or b) turn the pure columns I am defining into some sort of ORM model that I can then use to filter on the properties of the ORM model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is pretty awesome.  You can define the function using [DDLEvents](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.DDLEvents) and then call the function using `func` and define the output with [table_valued](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.table_valued) there is a different method for a scalar but its in the same docs.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
    event,
    column,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
    DDL,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(8), index=True)


event.listen(
    User.__table__,
    "after_create",
    DDL("""CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transformed (int) RETURNS TABLE (id integer, username varchar)
    AS $$ SELECT id, name AS username FROM users WHERE id = $1 $$
    LANGUAGE sql;
"""))


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)



with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    for name in ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']:
        session.add(User(name=name))

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    # Get a single row with id 1
    fn = func.transformed(1).table_valued(
        column("id", Integer),
        column("username", String))

    # This filtering is redundant because we selected
    # a user by its id but it demonstrates referencing the column
    # we defined above.
    q = select(fn).where(fn.c.username.like('User %'))
    for id, user in session.execute(q).all():
        print(id, user)
```

This prints out

```
1 User 1
```

The actual query looks like this, via `echo=True`:

```sql
SELECT anon_1.id, anon_1.username 
FROM transformed(%(transformed_1)s) AS anon_1 
WHERE anon_1.username LIKE %(username_1)s
```

Comment: I'm not sure if there is any way to map this to an object.  Seems that it would be hard to build relations with this so it probably wouldn't be that helpful to do it anyways.  Can a function returned table have foreign keys ?  Seems kind of crazy if it could.

Comment: You can also use the function result with `subquery()` to join against a regular mapped class.

Comment: Hey Ian, this looks pretty interesting. How exactly does the model know that there is an additional column called "username" now? Is that where the table_valued comes in?

Comment: @Julius Yes from the `column()` in the call to `table_valued()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possible solution but it's very similar to simply constructing the query via raw text:

```py
query = build_query(user_id).where(text("id = 4"))
```

Not a huge fan since it's not easy to expand on this dynamically.